# WP Theme Code Is All In One Line

Tags: html, wordpress, optimization, themes

I am searching for a WP theme for my website. After checking the source code, I've been noticing that there are many themes that are written entirely of one line of code.  In order to see all of the code, you have to scroll to the right for a long time before getting to the end.

Aside from being horribly uncomfortable and inconvenient in terms of modifying the code, is there any technical disadvantage to using a theme that has been constructed this way?  I ask because many of these themes are being purchased in fairly large quantities...

Clarification: It's not the source code itself, but when I click "view source" in my browser, the output here is in one line. Is this also normal or a sign minification?

Comment: Are you referring to the css? If so it has been minified.

Comment: Long shot, but are you using an editor like Notepad to look at the code? Maybe the files have Unix line endings and your editor doesn't understand them.

Comment: There is no disadvantage, if it has been minified it will speed up loading times!

Comment: If it's not the source code, why do you care? It's the source code that you modify... It appears to be minification. It has no disadvantages.